# Exercise 8, chapter 5 of Stein's Fourier analysis

Tags: fourier-analysis

> 8. Show that for any $a\ne0$, and $\sigma$ with $0<\sigma<1$, the sequence $\langle an^\sigma\rangle$ is equidistributed in $[0,1)$.
>
>    [Hint: Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^Ne^{2\pi ibn^\sigma}=O(N^\sigma)+O(N^{1-\sigma})$ if $b\ne0$.] In fact, note the following $$\sum_{n=1}^Ne^{2\pi ibn^\sigma}-\int_1^Ne^{2\pi ibn^\sigma}\mathrm dx=O\left(\sum_{n=1}^Nn^{-1+\sigma}\right)$$

I have proved $O(N^\sigma)$,but I can't prove that $\int=O(N^{1-\sigma})$

Comment: Sorry, I can't rotate my head like that.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you attempted to prove the statement in the hint? Do you see how that's relevant?

Comment: if we prove that equation ,we can use the Weyl's criterion to get the anwser

Answer (score 0):

Put
$$u_n=\exp(2\pi bn^{\sigma})-\int_n^{n+1}\exp(2\pi ix^{\sigma}dx=\int_n^{n+1}(\exp(2\pi bn^{\sigma})-\exp(2\pi ix^{\sigma}))dx$$

We have
$$\exp(2i\pi bn^{\sigma})-\exp(2\pi ix^{\sigma})=\exp(i\pi (n^{\sigma}+x^{\sigma}))(2\sin(\pi b(n^{\sigma}-x^{\sigma}))$$

Hence
$$|\exp(2i\pi bn^{\sigma})-\exp(2\pi ix^{\sigma})|\leq 2|\sin(\pi b(n^{\sigma}-x^{\sigma}))|\leq 2|b|\pi (x^{\sigma}-n^{\sigma})$$
and then:
$$|u_n|\leq 2\pi |b|(\frac{(n+1)^{\sigma+1}-n^{\sigma+12}}{\sigma+1}-n^{\sigma})$$

Now there exist $c_1\in ]n,n+1[$ such that $\displaystyle (\frac{(n+1)^{\sigma+1}-n^{\sigma+12}}{\sigma+1}=c_1^{\sigma}\leq (n+1)^{\sigma}$, and in the same way $(n+1)^{\sigma}-n^{\sigma}=\sigma c_2^{\sigma-1}\leq n^{\sigma-1}$ (as $-1+\sigma<0$), and it is easy to finish.

Comment: it can prove that∑- ∫=O(∑n^(-1+σ))=O(N^(σ)),but I want to know how to prove that∫=O(N^(1-σ))